# Is it possible to check the type of an argument passed to a function and treat it accordingly in JAVA?

Tags: java, generic-programming

For example, there needs to be a written a generic program for addition. It needs to be intelligent in a way that it determines the type of arguments passed to it and then output the answer in the same type.
For more elaboration:

> If I want to write only one method to add two numbers ( of any type
>   like int, float, double etc), what should I do that the method itself
>   determines the type of number passed and returns the calculated sum in
>   the same type?

Is there any way to sort this out? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Code view: For example arguments passed are 5 & 6 i.e. integers.

```
addition(5,6);
```

Now, what I want is a function add that somehow determines the type (i.e. integer in this case) & returns the result. Like:

`public (determined return type) add((determined returned type) space variable, (determined returned type) space variable){
return result;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static <T extends Number> T addition(T a, T b) {
    if (a instanceof Integer)
        return (T) (Object) (a.intValue() + b.intValue());

    // + similar code for all primitive types and possibly also BigInteger and BigDecimal
}
```

Comment: What is T in this case?

Comment: Generic type parameter that is determined at runtime.

Comment: What should be the return type of function that calls a generic method? In this case = "add(a,b)"

Comment: The return type is T, the same type as the type of parameters.

Comment: oops. I asked in a wrong way!
i meant: I called it from another class with the help of class' object.
when the generic method returns the result it has to be stored in some variable... Of what type it should be?
Like we use : int result = add(5,6);
With what "int" should be replaced in case of unknown type output?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method declared:

`public <N extends Number> N add(N n1, N n2)`

This would require `instanceof` checks to actually implement and return the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

More complex answer.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Number> T addition (T argA, T argb)
{
    if(argA instanceof Integer)
    {
        return (T)new Integer ((Integer)argA + (Integer)argb);
    }
    else if (argA instanceof Double)
    {
        return (T)new Double((Double)argA + (Double)argb);
    }
    //..
}
```